# How can I perform a clear of a DIV

Tags: css

I have this code and I would like the paragraph that follows to be left aligned and below:

```
<div class="content_hdr clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix content_hdr_heading">System Test</div>
    <div class="content_hdr_intro">
    <p>
Some text
    </p></div>
</div>

.clearfix:after{
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

div.content_hdr_heading {
    float: left;
    background: #ff9999;
}
```

I created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HmkMj/)

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Why is the heading left-floated? There doesn't appear to be anything to its right.

Comment: Also, consider heading elements (H1, H2, ...) for the heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="content_hdr">
    <div class="content_hdr_heading">System Test</div>
    <div class="content_hdr_intro">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>

.content_hdr_heading {
    float: left;
    background: #ff9999;
}

.content_hdr_intro {
    clear: left;
}
```

Since in this case there's a clearing element after the float, it's not necessary, but I usually put this on the containing element of floats to save headaches with following content:

```
.content_hdr {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: The heading has a background. Without the float left then the background goes from one side of the page to the other. Then the content goes below but it's not what I want. I just want the background to go under the heading words.

Comment: @Marilou Yeah, I guessed that after all, makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I decided to use your nice solution. Marilou

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

HTML:

```
<div class="content_hdr">
    <div class="content_hdr_heading">
        <h2>System Test</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content_hdr_intro">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.content_hdr_heading {
    overflow:auto;    
}

div.content_hdr_heading h2 {
    float: left;
    background: #ff9999;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/HmkMj/3/

Comment: Thanks Sime. I decided to use the other solution but thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

p { clear:both; }

You do not need the clearfix you have there. That seems redundant. If its a heading tag using an h1,h2 etc.